# read_csv stops at 100000

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to import a `.csv` file from my Downloads folder.
Usually, the `read_csv` function will import the entire rows, though there are millions of rows.
In this case, my file has `236,905` rows, but exactly `100,000` are loaded.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\df.csv',nrows=9999999,low_memory=False)
```

Comment: Are you saying that there's no error emitted?

Comment: with this code, no. 
if I get rid of the low_memory=False, the following error message will appear:
"DtypeWarning: Columns (10,11,12,13) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,"

Answer (score 2):

I come across the same problem with a file containing 5M rows.

I tried first this option :

```
 tp = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
 data_customers = pd.concat(tp, ignore_index=True)
```

It did work but in my case some rows where not read properly since some columns contained the character ',' which is used as delimiter in read_csv

The other solution is to use [Dask](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.read_csv.html#dask.dataframe.read_csv) It has an object called "DataFrame" (as Pandas). Dask reads your file and construct a dask dataframe composed of several pandas dataframe.
It's a great solution for parallel computing.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to create chunks using the `chunksize=` parameter:

```py
temporary = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\df.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
df = pd.concat(temporary, ignore_index=True)
```

`ignore_index` resets the index so it's not repeating.